# 'No pictures are available on the phone' after selecting contact picture

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

After upgrading my Nexus 5 to vanilla Lollipop a few days ago, I'm no longer able to assign pictures to my contacts. I can tap "Choose photo" and select a picture, but when I confirm I get the error "No pictures are available on the phone". How can this happen? It doesn't make any sense. I already tried wiping cache from recovery because some people say that it can fix some upgrade problems, but that didn't solve anything for me.

Comment: I've got the same problem. It seems a proper bug. I've opened an issue on android.

Comment: Here's the link for future readers: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80352

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a gallery app installed like the default "Gallery" or "QuickPic" app.

I had the same issue since "Gallery" doesn't come with Android 5.0 Lollipop, only "Photos" (which I disabled since I don't use Google+)

Comment: I was able to browse through my photos but *after* selecting the photo the error popped up. I was able to resolve it by installing a third-party photo editor.